# How to update the database when users download an ActiveStorage blob attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

Currently users can download an ActiveStorage blob in my app using the following link:

```
link_to 'download', rails_blob_path(pj.document.file, disposition: 'attachment')
```

However, I would like to update an attribute in the database for the associated model to register when the file was first downloaded.  This field is called the downloaded_at field.

I have made the following attempt:

1. Changed the link_to > button_to as I'm updating the model.
2. Added the appropriate route
3. Added the following code in the database:

   ```
   def download
       @proofreading_job = ProofreadingJob.find(params[:id])
       @proofreading_job.update(downloaded_at: Time.current) if current_user == @proofreading_job.proofreader.user
       response.headers["Content-Type"] = @proofreading_job.document.file.content_type
       response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; #{@proofreading_job.document.file.filename.parameters}"

       @proofreading_job.document.file.download do |chunk|
         response.stream.write(chunk)
       end
       ensure
       response.stream.close
   end
   ```

However, this does not do anything except redirect to the @proofreading_job page which is not what I want.

Has anyone done this before and if so how can I accomplish this task.

Comment: I think  your code should work... is there any error while updating, you can try @proofreading_job.update!(downloaded_at: Time.current) to raise exception in case it is failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used some javascript to capture the click of the button as follows:

```
    td = link_to rails_blob_path(pj.document.file, disposition: 'attachment'), 
         id: pj.document.id, 
   download: pj.document.file_name, 
      class: "btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm btn-download" do
        =pj.document.file_name 
        i.fa.fa-download.ml-3 aria-hidden="true"
```

coffee script:

```
  $('.btn-download').on 'click', (e) ->
    id = $(this).attr('id')
    $.ajax {url: Routes.document_path(id), type: 'PUT'}
```

routes.rb

```
resources :documents, only: [:show, :update]
```

documents_controller.rb:

```
  def update
    document = Document.find(params[:id])
    authorize([:proofreaders, document]) 
    document.update(downloaded_at: Time.current) if document.downloaded_at.nil?
    head :ok
  end
```

This seems to work very well. It updates the database and the user gets the file downloaded to their computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try using your action controller as a proxy, the concept is this:

1. download the file in your action
2. check if it is downloaded successfully and other validations
3. perform clean up operations (in your case the added code in your #3)
4. send the file back to user using the [send_data/send_file](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html) rendering method

E.g. in your controller:

```
def download
  file = open(params[:uri])
  validate!
  cleanup!
  send_file file.path
end
```

Then in your view:

```
link_to 'download', your_controller_path
```

Above is just concept and I apologize for only providing pseudo code in advance.